# Create many classes and be able to reference to them

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm working on simple game in Python and Pyglet. I want to give possibility to shoot so I create a bullet class. If I create one instance of that class for example
`self.new_bullet = bullet()`
I'm able to have only one instance at the moment. My question is how to create many instances at same time and be be able to refer to them and their variables? Example code (with pieces of pseudocode):

```
if key pressed:
    self.new_bullet = bullet()

... somewhere in main loop ...
bullet_image.blit(new_bullet.x, new_bullet.y)
self.new_bullet.x += 5

class bullet:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pos_x = player.pos_x
        self.pos_y = player.pos_y
```

So how should I create as many bullets as player wishes and still be able to give them speed and update their positions on screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want a list of bullet objects. Then, you can add to your list using `append`, and during your main loop you can iterate through all of them using a `for` loop.

```
self.bullets = []
self.bullets.append(bullet())
self.bullets.append(bullet())
```

In your main loop:

```
for bullet in self.bullets:
    bullet_image.blit(bullet.x, bullet.y)
    bullet.x += 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You might also want your bullets to be [`Sprites`](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.sprite.Sprite-class.html) grouped to a [`Batch`](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.graphics.Batch-class.html) for [faster execution](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/programming_guide/batched_rendering.html) (in case of heavy fire). The `pyglet`docs [show how its done](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.sprite-module.html#rst-drawing-multiple-sprites):

```
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

bullet_image = pyglet.image.load('bullet.png')
bullet_sprites = [] # I've changed the variable names to fitting our issue
for i in range(100):
  x, y = i * 10, 50
  bullet_sprites.append(pyglet.sprite.Sprite(bullet_image, x, y, batch=batch)
```

First, a fresh `Batch` is created. Next, 100 distinct `Sprite` objects are instantiated, each of which acts as a well-suited container for one bullet (or balls, but let's pretend we've got bullets here).
Each call of the `Sprite` constructor passes an optional reference to our `batch`, thus attaching all newly created bullet `Sprites` to the bullet `Batch`.

The beauty of it is the `draw()` method of the `Batch` class. When calling it, care is taken of the blitting of every bullet in the batch. You don't have to call each bullet `Sprite`'s `draw()` method yourself, because that can be done [more efficiently](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.graphics-module.html#rst-batches-and-groups) in only one single call:

```
@window.event
def on_draw():
  batch.draw()
```

You will recognize that this example, much like the one @Xymostech gave in the first answer, populates a list with all bullet instances as well. You will still need a Collection structure like this to keep the references to your `Sprite`s, since `Batch` has no function that would return a list of the objects attached to it.

So, you will stick with the solution in the previous answer, except for the Image blitting of course.
Another advantage of using `Sprites` is that you don't have to equip your `bullet` class with its own positional fields, because you can use the corresponding [parameters of your `Sprite` objects](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.sprite.Sprite-class.html#position). Beside allowing to update its `(x, y)` coordinates, `Sprites` can also [rotate](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.sprite.Sprite-class.html#rotation) and [fade out](http://www.pyglet.org/doc/api/pyglet.sprite.Sprite-class.html#opacity).

Actually, you should consider modifying your `bullet` class into being an extension of the `Sprite` class by [inheriting](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance) from it.

```
class Bullet(pyglet.sprite.Sprite): # btw, class names usually start with an Uppercase letter
  def __init__(self):
    super(pyglet.sprite.Sprite, self).__init__()
    self.x = player.pos_x
    ...
```

Comment: I thought that after adding to batch sprite cannot be moved, I'll surely try that, thanks!